# How to hot reload Flutter app having multiple async load calls

Tags: flutter

See my main.dart code below. I have quite a bit of async load calls and dependency injection registrations at the startup. I also have firebase and admob integration.

It used to hot reload but it does not anymore. How can I fix this?

```
GetIt getIt = GetIt.instance;
ThemeManager _themeManager = ThemeManager();
InappService _inappService = InappService();
PlayerInfoManagerService _playerInfoManagerService = PlayerInfoManagerService();
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  var authService = AuthService();
  getIt.registerSingleton<AuthService>(authService);
    .....
  getIt.registerSingleton<BotService>(BotService());

  if (kDebugMode) {
    RequestConfiguration configuration =
        RequestConfiguration(testDeviceIds: AdHelper.testDeviceIds);
    MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(configuration);
  }

  await _loadFlameAssets();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    precacheImage(const AssetImage("assets/images/you_avatar.png"), context);
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider<AppModel>(create: (_) => MyModel()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider<InappService>(create: (_) => _inappService),
          ChangeNotifierProvider<PlayerInfoManagerService>(
              create: (_) => _playerInfoManagerService),
        ],
        builder: (context, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'MyApp',
            theme: lightTheme,
            darkTheme: darkTheme,
            themeMode: _themeManager.themeMode,
            onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
            navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
            home: const MainMenuPage(),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Hot reload does not re-run anything set up in the globals.  For those you need a hot-restart.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I am not trying to reload globals, I want to see UI changes when I make a simple change like changing text widget's text to a new string. At the moment, when I do such simple changes, hot reload is stuck at  "preforming hot reload".